# Dispatch an action creator after the execution of the render method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently working on a react-redux app.I have a Selectable list component which takes it own state.I need to dispatch an action creator to redux to filter some data.My code looks pretty much like

```
handleClick(currentIndex){
  this.setState({
    active:currentIndex,
  })
}
componentDidUpdate(){
  //Dispatching an action here
  //Also a route change happens here(But clearly after debugging I found its not a causer of the lag)
}
render(){
   return (
     <List> 
        <ListItem onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
        <ListItem onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
     </List>
   )
}
```

So when I click my list item it gets a background color decided by its state.My componentDidupdate also dispatches the action and produce correct results.
The issue that I am facing here is, there is a lag in changing the color of the list Item ,which after debugging I found the list component is rendered only after redux finishes its job even though I trigger a setState for the list component.My data set is also not huge(but might grow huge which worries me).

So Is there a lifecycle hook which I can use after the render is complete.Any help on this would be grateful and will solve my performance trouble

Note:My List Component is independent of my redux state and has only action dispatcher mapped to it

Comment: May be you could set up a working fiddle? Would be much easier to try to help.

Comment: http://www.webpackbin.com/NJ2Nd-0QG here is a ready boilerplate for redux-form, you can edit it.

Comment: Why you wont move active property to global state? It would fix your issue I guess.

Comment: I can try that @MariuszJasinski

Comment: @Anarion I cannot host it anywhere right now

Comment: I gave you the link, you don't have to host it, it's a live fiddle. Very convinient to show some code here, at SO.